# Hibernate reflection issue. org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, hibernate-mapping

My application uses two tables: 'users' and 'user_profiles' (DB - PostgreSQL 9.2):

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
"id" SERIAL,
"email" varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
"password" varchar(255) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY("id")
);

CREATE TABLE "user_profiles" (
"id" SERIAL,
"user_id" int4 UNIQUE NOT NULL,
"name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
"surname" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
"patronymic" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("id"),
CONSTRAINT "ref_user_profiles_to_users" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id")
    REFERENCES "users"("id")
MATCH SIMPLE
ON DELETE RESTRICT
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
NOT DEFERRABLE
);
```

Here it is the mapping code for Users:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "users",
     uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"})
})
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(
        name = "findUserByProviderAndUid",
        query = "from Users u where u.provider = :provider AND u.uid =:uid",
        fetchSize = 1
)})
public class Users implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 126487584578L; 
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;

@Email
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
private String email;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
private String password;   

@OneToOne(fetch = LAZY, mappedBy = "users")
private UserProfiles userProfile;
//geters and setters
```

Here it is the mapping code for UserProfiles:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_profiles", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"inn"}),
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id"}),
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"passport_seria", "passport_number"})})
@XmlRootElement
public class UserProfiles implements Serializable {    
private static final long serialVersionUID = 12636847237L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name="id")
private Integer id;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
private String name;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(nullable = false, length = 255)
private String surname;   

@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false,  unique = true)
@OneToOne(fetch = LAZY)
private Users users;
//getters and setters
```

Every time I select Users I receive next stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.interpretator.kassa.model.UserProfiles.users
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValue(ComponentType.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getHashCode(ComponentType.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.generateHashCode(EntityUniqueKey.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.EntityUniqueKey.<init>(EntityUniqueKey.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:755)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1114)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2148)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2385)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:767)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:505)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1114)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl.uniqueResult(AbstractQueryImpl.java:966)
    at com.interpretator.kassa.dao.UsersDAOImpl.getUserByProviderAndUid(UsersDAOImpl.java:32)
    at com.interpretator.kassa.service.AuthenticationServiceImpl.currentUser(AuthenticationServiceImpl.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.currentUser(Unknown Source)
    at com.interpretator.kassa.config.filters.TokenAuthenticationFilter.processTokenAuthentication(TokenAuthenticationFilter.java:132)
    at com.interpretator.kassa.config.filters.TokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(TokenAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.interpretator.kassa.model.Users field com.interpretator.kassa.model.UserProfiles.users to java.lang.Integer
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    ... 83 more
```

This is the method in UsersDAO:

```
@Override
public Users getUserByProviderAndUid (String provider, String uid) throws NotFoundException {

    Users user = (Users) hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("findUserByProviderAndUid")
            .setParameter("provider", provider)
            .setParameter("uid", uid)
            .uniqueResult();

    if (user == null) {

        throw new NotFoundException ("Not found user with such provider and uid");
    }

    return user;
}
```

UPDATED - here it is the hql trace

```
Hibernate: 
select
    users0_.id as id1_16_,
    users0_.account_confirmed_at as account_2_16_,
    users0_.account_type as account_3_16_,
    users0_.confirmation_token as confirma4_16_,
    users0_.count_confirm_phone as count_co5_16_,
    users0_.created_at as created_6_16_,
    users0_.current_log_in_at as current_7_16_,
    users0_.current_sign_in_ip as current_8_16_,
    users0_.email as email9_16_,
    users0_.email_verified_time as email_v10_16_,
    users0_.last_login_time as last_lo11_16_,
    users0_.last_sign_in_ip as last_si12_16_,
    users0_.locked_at as locked_13_16_,
    users0_.login_failed_attempts as login_f14_16_,
    users0_.password as passwor15_16_,
    users0_.password_confirmed_at as passwor16_16_,
    users0_.password_reset_at as passwor17_16_,
    users0_.password_reset_token as passwor18_16_,
    users0_.phone as phone19_16_,
    users0_.phone_code as phone_c20_16_,
    users0_.phone_code_confirmed_at as phone_c21_16_,
    users0_.phone_verified_time as phone_v22_16_,
    users0_.provider as provide23_16_,
    users0_.sign_in_count as sign_in24_16_,
    users0_.status as status25_16_,
    users0_.token as token26_16_,
    users0_.uid as uid27_16_,
    users0_.unssuccess_login_time as unssucc28_16_,
    users0_.updated_at as updated29_16_ 
from
    users users0_ 
where
    users0_.provider=? 
    and users0_.uid=?
Hibernate: 
select
    userprofil0_.id as id1_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.created_at as created_2_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.dob as dob3_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.gender as gender4_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.inn as inn5_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.interests as interest6_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.issuer as issuer7_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.issuer_date as issuer_d8_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.name as name9_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.passport_number as passpor10_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.passport_seria as passpor11_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.patronymic as patrony12_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.surname as surname13_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.updated_at as updated14_14_0_,
    userprofil0_.user_id as user_id15_14_0_ 
from
    user_profiles userprofil0_ 
where
    userprofil0_.user_id=?
```

Comment: Share the code that generates this exception.

Comment: see updated question

Comment: Where is the namedQuery findUse‌​rByProviderAndUid ?

Comment: `Can not set com.interpretator.kassa.model.Users field com.interpretator.kassa.model.UserProfiles.users to java.lang.Integer` -> Mistake is in your query. Provide the query which results in this error..

Comment: @BillBilal, namedQuery is defined in Users. I have deleted it this post to save space :). Now the code for Users is updated.

Comment: What is provider in this query ? I don't see it in your users Entity.

Comment: @AntonSalnikov, enable `show_sql` property in hibernate configuration and see the query which is generated by hibernate..

Comment: What is provider in your query ?

Comment: @user1354678, please see updated post.

Comment: @BillBilal, it is additional field, it is present in code. Just in post it was eliminated to save space.

Comment: @user1354678, as you see there are two requests. After the second exception appears

Comment: It said that in your query you're asking hibernate to set a User object to an Integer but I don't see it in your query !

Comment: @BillBilal, Exactly, the problem appears just in when hibernate tries to bind UserProfiles to Users. But reflection issue appears.